# how to express previous value as product of previous rows

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to initialize 3 columns of a data.table as a product of previous rows.
i have a formula like this:

```
tableA[0,] = values
```

for each col:

```
tableA[i, col] = tableA[i - 1, col] * exp(tableB[i -1, col] * tableC[i, col]
```

(columns 1, 2 and 3 are completely independant)

I feel like i should use `cumprod` but i really don't see how (of course i can solve the problem with a for loop in 5sec)

Any one could please help me?

---

Also bonus question, would there be a reference site with some examples translating various mathematical formula with sums or prods so that I could familiarize my self with not using for loops.

I have written a little example below.
For ex the expected values for `tableA[, .(valA1)]` would be :

```
1.2, 1.620, 3.605, 8.867, 19.734
```

assuming no mistake in excel

Thank you!

```
tableA <- data.table( valA1 = rep(0, 5), valA2 = rep(0, 5), valA3 = rep(0, 5))
tableA[1, valA1 := 1.2]
tableA[1, valA2 := 1.1]
tableA[1, valA3 := 1.3]
    
tableB <- data.table(valB1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5),
                     valB2 = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6),
                     valB3 = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7))
tableC <- data.table(valC1 = c(2, 3, 4, 3, 2),
                     valC2 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
                     valC3 = c(5, 3, 3, 2, 2))
tableA[, ValB1 := shift(tableB$valB1)]
tableA[, ValB2 := shift(tableB$valB2)]
tableA[, ValB3 := shift(tableB$valB3)]
    
tableA[, ValC1 := tableC$valC1]
tableA[, ValC2 := tableC$valC2]
tableA[, ValC3 := tableC$valC3]
    
tableA[, Exp1 := exp(ValB1 * ValC1)]
tableA[, Exp2 := exp(ValB2 * ValC2)]
tableA[, Exp3 := exp(ValB3 * ValC3)]
    
tableA[-1, ValA1 := cumprod something?]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there.

#### How to use `cumprod()`

According to OP's description, the rule for computing the `ValA` columns *iteratively* is

a<sub>i</sub> = a<sub>i-1</sub> * f<sub>i</sub>

where f<sub>i</sub> are constants which are computed from the `ValB` and `ValC` columns

So, for i = 1 we get

a<sub>1</sub> = a<sub>0</sub> * f<sub>1</sub> ,

for i = 2, we get

a<sub>2</sub> = a<sub>1</sub> * f<sub>2</sub> = a<sub>0</sub> * f<sub>1</sub> * f<sub>2</sub> ,

and so forth. If this is being continued to i = n we get

a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>0</sub> * f<sub>1</sub> * f<sub>2</sub> * ... * f<sub>n-1</sub> * f<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>0</sub> * cumprod(f)

#### A `fill` parameter for `shift()` is required

Now, we need to consider the value of b<sub>0</sub>. According to OP's formula

f<sub>n</sub> = e<sup>b<sub>i-1</sub>c<sub>i</sub></sup>

For i = 1, this becomes

f<sub>1</sub> = e<sup>b<sub>0</sub>c<sub>1</sub></sup>

so we need to define b<sub>0</sub> as 0 in the call to shift()

```
shift(ValB, fill = 0)
```

so that f<sub>1</sub> = 1. Otherwise, f<sub>1</sub> would be `NA` and cumprod(f) would become `NA` as well.

#### Define a function

Now, this can be wrapped up in a function definition:

```
myfunc <- function(a, b, c) first(a) * cumprod(exp(shift(b, fill = 0) * c))
```

When called with the sample datsets

```
myfunc(tableA$valA1, tableB$valB1, tableC$valC1)
```

it returns the expected result:

> [1]  1.200000  1.619831  3.604999  8.866867 19.733576

#### Dealing with *multiple* independent columns

The OP has pointed out that

> columns 1, 2 and 3 are completely independent

Coding the same operations for a different set of columns is quite tedious. Therefore, I suggest to *reshape*  and combine the datasets.

```
A <- melt(tableA, measure.vars = patterns("valA"), value.name = "a")
A[, b := melt(tableB, measure.vars = patterns("valB"))$value]
A[, c := melt(tableC, measure.vars = patterns("valC"))$value]
A[]
```

> ```
>     variable   a   b c
>  1:    valA1 1.2 0.1 2
>  2:    valA1 0.0 0.2 3
>  3:    valA1 0.0 0.3 4
>  4:    valA1 0.0 0.4 3
>  5:    valA1 0.0 0.5 2
>  6:    valA2 1.1 0.2 1
>  7:    valA2 0.0 0.3 2
>  8:    valA2 0.0 0.4 3
>  9:    valA2 0.0 0.5 1
> 10:    valA2 0.0 0.6 2
> 11:    valA3 1.3 0.3 5
> 12:    valA3 0.0 0.4 3
> 13:    valA3 0.0 0.5 3
> 14:    valA3 0.0 0.6 2
> 15:    valA3 0.0 0.7 2
> ```

Now, all input data are combined in one data.table in long format whereby each independent dataset is identified by the value of `variable`. `myfunc()` can be applied on each group:

```
A[, myfunc(a, b, c), by = variable]
```

> ```
>     variable        V1
>  1:    valA1  1.200000
>  2:    valA1  1.619831
>  3:    valA1  3.604999
>  4:    valA1  8.866867
>  5:    valA1 19.733576
>  6:    valA2  1.100000
>  7:    valA2  1.641007
>  8:    valA2  4.036226
>  9:    valA2  6.021342
> 10:    valA2 16.367705
> 11:    valA3  1.300000
> 12:    valA3  3.197484
> 13:    valA3 10.616021
> 14:    valA3 28.857337
> 15:    valA3 95.809732
> ```

This result can be reshaped to wide format again

```
dcast(A[, myfunc(a, b, c), by = variable], rowid(variable) ~ variable)[, variable := NULL][]
```

> ```
>        valA1     valA2     valA3
> 1:  1.200000  1.100000  1.300000
> 2:  1.619831  1.641007  3.197484
> 3:  3.604999  4.036226 10.616021
> 4:  8.866867  6.021342 28.857337
> 5: 19.733576 16.367705 95.809732
> ```

Comment: thank you so much for looking at my problem @Uwe let me review/underdand it and I will confirm the solution. best.

Comment: thanks again for the detailed explanations, the cumprod how to , and the extra step with the multivar reshaping.